# Find struct elements with same ID but different other field values, from 2 struct arrays

Tags: algorithm, go

Code is similar to below:

```
    type Contact struct {
    Id    string
    Email string
}

type EmailDifference struct {
    Id       string
    OldEmail string
    NewEmail string
}

func main() {
    ContactList1 := []Contact{
        Contact{
            Id:    "A01",
            Email: "email1@mail.com",
        },
        Contact{
            Id:    "A02",
            Email: "secondemail@mail.com",
        },
        Contact{
            Id:    "C00",
            Email: "someemail@mail.com",
        },
    }

    ContactList2 := []Contact{
        Contact{
            Id:    "A01",
            Email: "email23441@mail.com",
        },
        Contact{
            Id:    "A02",
            Email: "2ndmail@mail.com",
        },
        Contact{
            Id:    "C00",
            Email: "someemail@mail.com",
        },
    }

    //How to find contacts with same ID but different emails from the above 2 contact lists?
}
```

I need to output a slice `[]EmailDifference{}` containing contacts with same ID but different emails. How to do it efficiently, without using 2 `for` loops (i.e. comparing each element of `ContactList1` with all elements of `ContactList2` until a match in ID is found, then note that result if 2 emails are different)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the two nested loops, you could use a `map`. Still requires two loops, but not nested. Whether this is more efficient than the nested loops, probably depends on the size of both lists.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Contact struct {
    Id    string
    Email string
}

type EmailDifference struct {
    Id       string
    OldEmail string
    NewEmail string
}

func main() {
    ContactList1 := []Contact{
        Contact{
            Id:    "A01",
            Email: "email1@mail.com",
        },
        Contact{
            Id:    "A02",
            Email: "secondemail@mail.com",
        },
        Contact{
            Id:    "C00",
            Email: "someemail@mail.com",
        },
    }

    ContactList2 := []Contact{
        Contact{
            Id:    "A01",
            Email: "email23441@mail.com",
        },
        Contact{
            Id:    "A02",
            Email: "2ndmail@mail.com",
        },
        Contact{
            Id:    "C00",
            Email: "someemail@mail.com",
        },
    }

    //How to find contacts with same ID but different emails from the above 2 contact lists?

    var diffs []EmailDifference

    // Convert ContactList2 to map
    ContactEmailMap2 := make(map[string]string, len(ContactList2))
    for _, c := range ContactList2 {
        ContactEmailMap2[c.Id] = c.Email
    }

    // Loop through ContactList1
    for _, c1 := range ContactList1 {
        c2email, isPresent := ContactEmailMap2[c1.Id]
        if isPresent && c1.Email != c2email {
            diffs = append(diffs, EmailDifference{Id: c1.Id, OldEmail: c1.Email, NewEmail: c2email})
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v", diffs)
}
```